# HTML onclick triggers code without clicking

Tags: c#, html, onclick

my code is executed without clicking on it (which results in nullpointers because its called too early), this is my code :

Site.Master

```
<input type="submit" onclick="<%MvcApplication2.MvcApplication.hc.setLang("nl");%>"    value="submit">
```

i have 3 questions about this situation

- is the code between <%..%> executed at compile time?
- is this even gonna work (putting <%%> in onclick)?
- is there a better way of calling methods from my C# class?

thx in advance

Comment: What are you _trying_ to do here?  The server-side code will be executed, well, server-side.  So it's going to execute that `setLang()` method when the view is being rendered on the server, before it ever gets sent to the client.  What does that `onclick` attribute contain in the rendered HTML?  I'm _guessing_ that it's empty, unless perhaps `setLang()` returns a string and the rendering engine defaults to displaying that string.

Comment: im not sure what you are trying to say, but ill try to answer. I want a submit button there, which calls the setLang("nl") method, this method will write the "nl" value to a cookie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is it because it executes the code between <%..%> at compile time?

Thats correct.

Code breaks get rendered server side before being passed to the client.

If you wish to only run this `onclick` of the `input` you could use [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to make a server side call to that method.

Comment: thanks 1 more question, if i get it to compile, will it call the method once i click on the button?? or will it only executed at compile time.

Comment: @DeadManWalking Using AJAX you would then call the method `onclick`

Answer (score 2):

correct - the value being passed to onclick is being evaluated when the page is called, as it is server side code - you'll need to

I would create a controller method that returns sets the language for example

Controller:

```
public string setlanguage(string id){
//set your language
return "some string value";
}
```

Controller (with void)

```
public void setlanguage(string id){
//set your language
}
```

Html:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="setLanguage('nl');"    value="submit">

<script type="text/javascript">
function setLanguage(lang)
$.post('@Url.Action("setlanguage","controllername")/' + lang,function(){
//no result has been returned
});
}
</script>
```

worth noting that if you're not returning a value then any changes to page language will likely not reflect until the next time the page loads - it may be better to use a full postback

Comment: i know it's probably my lack of knowledge, but this doesn't compile at all, neither do i expect a result, i just want to call a 'void' method

Comment: sorry - in the controller if you wanted a result you would add a return value, for a void you can simply call this I'v updated the answer to show you

Answer (score 0):

You should put your code that run when clicking the button inside a function then pass the function name to the onclick property.

by this way you could easily know if your code is correct or not.